# Simple Question About Conditional Flow Statements

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I have a piece of code which reads through Outlook emails and searches for emails based on specific criteria, however, the problem is that once all the emails have been found satisfying the criteria the code does not stop. It just keeps running even though it returns nothing more.

This is what I have so far:

I have tried using break statements and multiple if statements as well as elif. But I cannot seem to get it to work.

```
import win32com.client
from datetime import date, timedelta


outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(18).Folders.Item("Riscunit")
messages = inbox.Items

date = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
subject = "Catalyst"

for message in messages:
    if subject in message.subject and date == message.senton.date():
      print(message.sender)
      print(message.senton.date())
      print(message.senton.time())
      print(message.body)
    elif subject != message.subject and date != message.senton.date:
     break
```

I would like the code to retrieve the relevant emails and then stop running. I am new to Python so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try to use else instead of elif

Comment: How do you know that the code keeps running? Is the `messages` variable some sort of generator which blocks while it is waiting for more emails?

Comment: Try to run it in a IDE with a debugging environment where you can break. When you think it keeps running while there is no new message, break to understand where and under which conditions

Comment: Did you just mean `else: break`? so that on the first message which is either not the right subject or is not the right date the loop will quit?

Comment: @quamrana yes thats exactlly what I want. i've tried elif as well as else. neither seem to work correctly. i have tried ```else:break``` and when i run the code it jumps straight to the break statement and returns nothing. i am using an IDE and there are no indentation errors

Comment: Its probably because the messages are iterated over in some order or other, so you never know how many you want and how many you have to skip over to get to those you want. You may have to either scan over a limited number of messages or accept a limited number of matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to limit the number of messages you test to see whether they are what you want:

```
max = 42
for count, message in enumerate(messages):
    if count > max:
       break
    if subject in message.subject and date == message.senton.date():
       collect(message)   # Do something with this message (print or append to list)
```

Comment: thanks so much! i will try this. do you think this same concept would work if using a specified date range? because the mailbox I am searching has thousands of emails

Comment: Yes, you can have the conditional: `... and dateHigh>message.senton.date() and dateLow<message.senton.date():`

Comment: sorry to re-open this, i was just wondering why when trying to specify a sender instead of subject i get a type error ```TypeError: This object does not support enumeration```

Comment: This sounds like something for a separate question. Make up some simple test code that fails with this error and post the code and the full Traceback as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

- The `elif` is unnecessary as it's the opposite of the `if`
- If you really need to do something when `if` is false, then an `else` would be more appropriate--though it's likely you don' need an `else` here

```py
bag = ['pizza', 'ziplocks','bananas', 'milk glass', 'post-its','spray']
foods  = {1:'pizza', 2:'bananas', 3:'milk'}

# check shopping bag for food

for item in bag:
    for key in foods:
        if foods[key] in item:
            print('eat ' + foods[key]);
            break
    else:
        print('put ' + item + ' away');

print("done");
```

and here's another example that does something when your if condition is not met:

```py
messages = [{'subject': 'shopping list', 'date': '05/10/2019', 'body': 'milk'},
            {'subject': 'shopping list', 'date': '05/10/2019', 'body': 'pizza'},
            {'subject': 'holiday', 'date': '12/10/2015', 'body': 'need vacation soon'},
            {'subject': 'shopping list', 'date': '12/10/2015', 'body': 'we need potatoes'}]

date = '05/10/2019'
subject = "shopping list"

for item in messages:
    for key in item:
        if subject in item['subject'] and item['date'] == date:
            print('buy ' + item['body']);
            break
        else:
            print('archive \"' + item['body'] + '\" email');
            break

print("done");
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your response. The only issue I am having with using a break statement directly after the print lines is that it only prints one email for the requested day and then the code stops. It does not return all emails for the requested day.

Comment: similarly, if i put a break after an else statement, it seems to jump straight to the break statement and returns nothing at all

Comment: I see that you've since resolved this, which is great. In my example, the breaks were needed to avoid looping too many times. In your situation, you likely need to remove the breaks.

Answer (score -1):

It is probably because of the logic of using `elif` instead of `else`.

Try this:

```
import win32com.client
from datetime import date, timedelta


outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(18).Folders.Item("Riscunit")
messages = inbox.Items

date = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
subject = "Catalyst"

for message in messages:
    if subject in message.subject and date == message.senton.date():
      print(message.sender)
      print(message.senton.date())
      print(message.senton.time())
      print(message.body)
    else: 
      subject != message.subject and date != message.senton.date
      break
```

Comment: The contents of your `else:` make no sense.

Comment: Those are OP's, not mine. From how I understood the question, if the subject and date dont match what he is requesting, break from the loop.

Comment: Yes, but you changed something and posted it. I'm sure there will be a syntax error because of the colon at the end of the line.

Comment: You need a colon at the end of an `else` statement in python so I'm not sure what you are implying.

Comment: There is a colon at the end of the next line.

Comment: So it is not the else line that makes no sense, it was me missing the `:` at the end of the line within the else statement. Before downvoting, please try to help folks like me see typos. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193150/discussion-between-quamrana-and-jerry-m).

Comment: Sorry, I am on a company network and cannot use the chat feature currently :( @quamrana